# Trouble with Account Linking (Actions on Google)

Tags: actions-on-google

I've implemented an implicit flow for authorization and followed the directions on the docs for account linking, but when I redirect the url back to google, I get:

'Accounts failed to link. Please close your browser and try again'

My authorization URL is:
https://m-auth.herokuapp.com/dialog/authorize?client_id=abc123&redirect_uri=https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/trans-f4514&response_type=token&state=STATE

And my redirect after authorization through my app, is:
https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/trans-f4514#access_token=3c642a215cd0a2e8c8f00eb03535a6304aaf5739&token_type=bearer&state=STATE

When I test this on the playground I get:

[image]

Is this the correct req/response I should be getting?

I am also getting "Start Test Failed" when I try to test the app on the simulator.

Could it be a problem that the user is directed to a login screen?

Any clue as to why I am running into these problems? Thanks!

===========================================================================

UPDATE:
I changed the state parameter in the uri to STATE_STRING and it stopped saying that the linking failed, but it is not saying it was successful either:

[image]

Does it mean it was successful if I only get the above message?

Comment: I cannot completly answer your quastion but maybe this will help. Have you tried the oauth playground with a custom client id that has the redirect uri https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground? I think this is required for the oauth playground to verify your response. (Use the checkbox Use your own OAuth credentials)

Comment: So I tried what you have suggested and I am getting pretty much the same results with a different redirect uri. Judging from the picture I have posted above, is that how it should look like for a successful send? or should I be seeing something different?

Comment: @gnuhc did you get a solution for this?

Comment: nope, not yet :/

Answer (score 1):

You misconfigured your redirect url.

Currently the user is redirected to this url: 
`https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground&access_token=TOKEN&token_type=bearer&state=NULL`

Google OAuth required a format like: `https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/#access_token=TOKEN&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600`

You can test your OAuth endpoint with this [OAuth Playground configuration](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/#step1&scopes=user&url=https%3A%2F%2F&content_type=application%2Fjson&http_method=GET&useDefaultOauthCred=unchecked&oauthEndpointSelect=Custom&oauthAuthEndpointValue=https%3A%2F%2Fm-auth.herokuapp.com%2Fdialog%2Fauthorize&oauthClientId=abc123&includeCredentials=checked&accessTokenType=bearer&autoRefreshToken=unchecked&accessType=offline&prompt=consent&response_type=token). After granting access to your application you should see the OAuth Playground again but with Step 2 being activated. You can review the token that was retrieved by activating "Step 1's resultAccess token retrieved".

Comment: What would the required format be for an implicit flow? The token for an implicit flow does not have an expiration date I think.

Comment: I changed the value of the state query parameter and it stopped giving me 'Accounts failed to link' message, but I'm not sure if I was supposed to receive a message that linking was successful instead of just telling me to close the browser.